# Is there a Windows version controll client that supports Git, Mercurial, and Subversion (all in one)

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial, client

Is there a Windows version control **client** (*not* clients) that supports Git, Mercurial, and Subversion (all in one)?

I don't mind having `^Tortoise(Git|Hg|SVN)$`(*yes I wrote it as a regex*) installed but my context menu is getting unmanageable :)

It would be nice if there was something like [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) but for Windows.
And +1 if it integrated with Windows Explorer.

Comment: Shell expansion would have been more appropriate since you want to output text, and not check it :) Tortoise{Git,Hg,SVN}

Comment: SourceTree is now available also for windows, but currently it only support Git.
In the faq it's stated that the missing features in the windows version will be addressed in the next releases (no timeframe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SmartGit supports the three of them.

http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html

Comment: OK. I was hoping this would be "the answer" but this just seems to be Eclipse based client that still required downloading separate Hg and Git executables and then specifying them...Is there no "all in one" solution...

Comment: Hm, ok, I see better what you're looking for. No unfortunately, there are no clients shipped with Git and Hg executables versionned together in a single package :-/. It make sense in a way, since Hg and Git implementations for windows (and other os) are the result of efforts from other developper communities. Different implementation may exist and you are free to choose the one you like better. But is it really a big deal ? I don't know about Hg, but Git is really easy to install on Windows (through Msysgit). (BTW, SmartGit is not based on Eclipse, although it is written in java).

Comment: ( ... you're right about the fact that it's a shame that Atlassian does not provide a Windows version of its SourceTree client :-/ )

Comment: No it is not big deal. As I mention I have all 3 Tortoise clients installed for a while, but I was wondering if the was something like SourceTree for Windows.

Answer (score 4):

[TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) supports all 3. You have to install the [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.com/) and [hgsubversion](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home) plugins, but then you can work will all 3 VCS as Hg repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a client that supports all the three, but there is [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/documentation.html?page=concepts-git-svn) that supports either Git and SVN.

However if you can use eclipse as IDE, it allows to install plugins for several VCS system included Git, Hg, and SVN; so you with eclipse you can work with all these three without any problem ...

Comment: Yes I was aware of options to use IDE but I really need standalone client for sole purpose of version control.

Answer (score 0):

[SourceTree is now available for Windows](http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2013/09/16/sourcetree-for-windows-1-2-is-here/) too. It can use subversion repositories via the [hgsubversion](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/wiki/Home) extension, but reportedly on Mac the experience [might be wanting](http://www.third-helix.com/2013/09/using-sourcetree-with-subversion-hint-dont/) (a comment on that same post indicates the subversion bridge not so bad, and also that SourceTree is a tad git-centric and leaves out some useful hg options).